# Does Go has out of the box priority queue?

Tags: go

Does Go has out of the box priority queue (the one that I can just import from some module and start using like python's [priority queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.PriorityQueue))?

I know that priority queues are often implemented using heap data structure and go has a [heap package](http://golang.org/pkg/container/heap/), which also suggests how to use it to implement a queue (in **Example (PriorityQueue)** ), which I can easily grab and use.

My question is this a recommended way to do this, or there is an out of the box Priority Queue package that I failed to find?

Comment: is it really that bad?

Comment: Python's `Queue.PriorityQueue` isn't the recommended way to get a priority queue unless you specifically want to use it to exchange information across threads; it has a whole bunch of synchronization-related overhead associated with it, and several of the basic container operations have weird names because those operations don't make much sense in a multithreaded context.

Comment: @user2357112 thank you for a comment, but I have never told that `Queue.PriorityQueue` is recommended in python. I just gave it as an example of simple to import module (I didn't want to mention `heapq`, because I was afraid that people misinterpret it as I am looking for a heap module). What I am looking for is recommended way to use priority queue in go.

Comment: I don't know of a better way than the one mentioned in your question.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer this is sad. But thank you for clarifying this.

Answer (score -1):

Quoting Wikipedia:

> a priority queue is an abstract data type which is like a regular queue or stack data structure, but where additionally each element has a "priority" associated with it. [...] While priority queues are often implemented with heaps, they are conceptually distinct from heaps. A priority queue is an abstract concept like "a list" or "a map";

Go provides some basic data structures that are used in most applications but leave the implementation of more specialized data structures to the programmer. For example, the go map can be used to trivially implement a set.

[The example](http://golang.org/pkg/container/heap/) you link to uses a slice `[]*Item` to represent the more abstract type `heap.Interface` and also the (even more abstract) type `PriorityQueue`. Go is about composition and I would say that implementing `PriorityQueue` in terms of heap operations is good practice.

This gives you control as a programmer. If you want thread safety, use the composition of `PriorityQueue` and `sync.Mutex` to make it thread safe. If you want a different implementation than a heap, make `PriorityQueue` an interface and you can implement it however you want.

Of course there's a trade-off. In this case, the implementation was ~25 lines of code. If the implementation was  hundreds of lines you'd probably want to find a package that has done this already.

Comment: Thank you. Just find it strange that C++ gives such abstraction, and go decide to "give me control". Why not to give me control with implementing my heap, my sort (both implementations would not be big). Stoping my rant here.